# Trying to make a peak voltage adapter

Tags: voltage-measurement

I'm trying to make a PVA using the following schematic:

[image]

I have put something together that looks like:

[image]

Obviously the input at the top will have positive lead going into the diode and the negative lead on the other side.

Is this correct, I have little knowledge and not really sure about schematics. I want to use this to test my ignition system.

If it's wrong could someone point out what needs to be changed or draw a simplified version (I understand the schematic may be as simple as it gets) or alter the image of my PVA so it's usable?

Comment: You are missing a red wire between row 3 and 4 on the left side. You say you are testing your ignition system.... are you sure 400V is enough.... ignition systems usually work in the thousands of volts if not tens of thousands. WHat exactly are you planning on connecting this to.

Comment: Also Remember that source is current limited and dv/dt must match your rise time of result needed. So why such a large low V cap.?

Comment: I want to test an ignition coil which should be 100v minimum and a crakshaft position sensor which should be 0.7v minimum.

Comment: missing the wire on the left, so left side should mirror the right side? that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't connected together what you think you have.  The positive sides of the resistor and capacitor aren't connected to each other.  You're missing a jumper wire between them.

Comment: missing the wire on the left, so left side should mirror the right side? that makes sense. Should i have continuity through the whole circuit or would the capacitor stop continuity?

Comment: That depends what you're measuring continuity between.  The black in should connect straight to black out.  Red in should connect to red out, but only one way round because of the diode.  Between red and black, you should see 1Mohm.